# C - What is wrong with this code, it does not continue after user entered his guess?

Tags: c, scanf

as you saw up there the problem is that the loop does not continue after the users has entered his code, i am wondering why this is and if you have a better purpose for me. I am new to the C language help is much appreciated!!!!!!

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

        int randomNumber = 11;
        int usersGuess;
        int i;

        do {
                printf("You need to guess a number between 0 and 20! Good Luck! \n");

                for (i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                        printf("You have got %d amount of tries, Guess The random number: ", i);
                        scanf_s("%d", usersGuess);

                        if (usersGuess == randomNumber) {
                                printf("You won");
                                break;
                        } else if (usersGuess > randomNumber) {
                                printf("That is wrong, random number is less than that");
                        } else if (usersGuess < randomNumber) {
                                printf("that is wrong, the random number is higher than that");
                        } else if (usersGuess > 20) {
                                printf("please guess again cause the random number is between 0 and 20");
                        }
                }


        } while(i > 0);




        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(i > 0);`  - will this ever happen? And your usage of `scanf_s` is invalid. Read its documentation please.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, if the user guesses correctly.

Comment: @Angew Right. Yet I don't see how it serves the logic of this program...

Comment: @EugeneSh. It does not.

Comment: `else if (usersGuess > 20) {` is an impossible condition to reach, because you already matched on `> randomnumber`

Comment: Also, the outer while loop `} while(i > 0);` seems of little value, I suppose you want the game to keep re-playing so long as the user guessed the value of `i`, but I will be inaccessible on the OUTER side of the FOR loop regardless of when you break it.  Even if that is not the case with the version of C you are using, then there is a further issue in that there is one WIN condition where the value of `i` will still = `0`. you will need to change to use `--i` instead of `i--` in order to avoid that, or change your While to be `} while(i >= 0 );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has Undefined Behaviour, which means it's buggy and anything can happen. The problem is that you're passing an integer to `scanf_s` where it want a pointer. Do this:

```
scanf_s("%d", &usersGuess);
```

The reason is that you want the function to write into the variable `usersGuess`. In C, all parameters are passed by value, so if you want an output parameter, you have to make it a pointer.

Comment: I thank you ! That was my mistake i must admit, idk how i come not to see that i will continue with wearing my glasses on. thanks doe means alot!!!